# Woocommerce: Order Summary in checkout Order comments field (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I would like the order summary of a woocommerce order to be shown in a field at checkout. I am able to put plain text in a field but when I tried to add a hook it throws error codes. This is the code to add default text to the field. Located in the `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'default_values_checkout_fields' );

function default_values_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

$fields['order']['order_comments']['default'] = ' I would like the hook here ';

return $fields;
}
```

This code outputs a table in the checkout:

```
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">

<tbody>
    <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <td class="product-name">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                                                                            </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
```

It is a table but I would like the text from the table to show in a field if not the table.

Comment: What is the error you say is thrown?

Comment: Please clarify your question as it's very incomplete and unclear as it is now.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'woocommerce_review_order_befor' (T_STRING) in /homepages/6/d651498966/htdocs/clickandbuilds/rxbsystem/wp-content/themes/woffice-child/functions.php on line 147

Comment: woo commerce uses a class called variation-Details to show details of products placed in a cart it is these details I want echoed into a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is not very detailed, here you get an example that will display in the Order comments checkout fields all product titles:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_order_comments_checkout_fields' );
function custom_order_comments_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    if ( !WC()->cart->is_empty()):

    $output = '';
    $count = 0;
    $cart_item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ):

        $count++;

        // Displaying the product title
        $output .= 'Product title: ' . $cart_item['data']->post->post_title;

        // New line (for next item)
        if($count < $cart_item_count)
            $output .= '
';

    endforeach;

    $fields['order']['order_comments']['default'] = $output;

    endif;

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.

This code will display in the checkout Order comments fields something like this:

```html
Product title: My Product title 1
Product title: My Product title 2
...
```

> You can easily output product quantity and all kind of data that is in the cart object… You have just to clearly define in your question what you want to output and how *(without forgetting that this has to be raw data like, as is outputted in a text area field)*…

Code is tested and works.

Comment: This actually almost gives me what I want, my question has not been specific enough Im guessing. currently at checkout the cart shows “order summary”:  

Haircut Booking  × 1 

Details:

    Date: January 20, 2017
    Time: 10:30 am
    Service: Haircut (Adult)
    Hair Stylist: Mau


These details have not been input by any field in the woocommerce checkout but by another plugin which is able to add these details at the end of the actual woocommerce product “Haircut Booking”.

Comment: Your solution works in the sense that it shows the Haircut Booking product in the order notes but it is actually the details below that I am after. These variables are not listed wiith the product.

Comment: This answer does what I need it to do so far, I need to investigate the plugin further to understand how it shows the text when it does I will pass it on to you but the solution you gave does what I need it to do so far, thanks.